# sumif of current date and time with indirect Match

Tags: excel-formula

How do I modify the following to include to look a the current time and compare to named range.

```
=SUMIF(3:3,TODAY(),INDIRECT("a"&MATCH("total",A:A,0)):INDIRECT("z"&MATCH("total",A:A,0)))
```

I need determine the sum of values where column A value = "workingProgresssubtotal" and row 4(time)is <= current time for current date.
return sum(workingProgressSubtotal)

also repeat process the ColumnA = Total.

Note the number of rows will change on refresh, however the date and time rows will always be 3 &4 .

[embed=file 1052427]

Answer (score 0):

To fix your pasted formula use this:

```
=SUMIF(3:3,"<="&TODAY(),INDIRECT("A" & MATCH("total",A:A,0)&":Z" &MATCH("total",A:A,0)))
```

From there you can probably intuit how to do what you want.

Comment: =SUMIF(3:3,"<="&TODAY(),INDIRECT("A" & MATCH("total",A:A,0)&":Z" &MATCH("total",A:A,0)))

Comment: how do I include <= to current time - I tried Now()-today() but having issue with syntax.

Comment: sorry this still does not demostrate how to include the <= current hour, what is the correct syntax?

Comment: In excel use custom format on two cells.  The custom format is `mm/dd/yy hh:MM`.  Then in on put `=today()` and in the other put `=now()`.  `Today` will give you `12/10/2015 0:00` and `Now` will give you `12/10/2015 10:03` with the time being relative to your time zone.  So you want the values between those dates.  Look into `sumifs()` and using my formula as a back bone you should get `=SUMIFS(INDIRECT("A" & MATCH("total",A:A,0)&":Z" &MATCH("total",A:A,0)),3:3,"=>"&TODAY(),3:3,"<=" &NOW())`.  The hard part of this was the sum area not the criteria, google would have given you that answer.

Answer (score 0):

HERE IS MY FINAL SOLUTION - THANKS TO ALL WHO ASSISTED ME WITH THE ISSUE:

```
 =SUMPRODUCT(INDIRECT("a"&MATCH("WorkInProgressSubtotal",A:A,0)):INDIRECT("z"&MATCH("WorkInProgressSubtotal",A:A,0)),--(A3:Z3<=TODAY()),--(A4:Z4<=NOW()-TODAY()))
```